Space colonization book, first published in 1950s or 1960s, where people of Earth are being "drafted" to colonize other planets
People of Earth are being "drafted" to colonize other planets. A male volunteer gets the first choice of a single woman. He chooses an "experienced" female.  An innocent young lady goes to a young man. Eventually, they switch places.

Your description reminds me of a novel where the colonist choosing first forfeits his choice, because the young lady he chooses refuses, as the women have the right to do. Next in line is the protagonist, who can't believe his luck, asks the same young lady, who now accepts. Much later in the story, after the protagonist has turned out to be a capable colonist, there is indeed a swap of wives, because he has learned to appreciate capability more than beauty.
Sadly I do not recall more from that novel, but if these details match your memory of the novel, you could refine your question.

This is the book!

Based on the description you've provided, the book you're referring to is likely The Defiant Agents by Andre Norton, first published in 1962. In this novel, people from Earth are sent to colonize other planets, and the story involves complex relationships between characters, including partner dynamics similar to what you've described.

Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy SE! Please [edit] your answer to add more details on how this work answers the question. You can find tips on how to write a good identification answer and what details to add in our guide.

I've read The Defiant Agents and the only thing that matches is the colonizing a new planet - the agents (at least the ones from the USA; it doesn't mention how it works for the USSR ones) aren't even drafted.

Not THE DEFIANT AGENTS, but thanks for the contribution.
